# Shortcut to get a statement with certain pattern in R

Tags: regex, r

I have to write the following as it is.

```
('trial1' = Ozone1, 'trial2' = Ozone2, trial3 = Ozone3,...........trial1000 = Ozone1000)
```

I want to write this with one command in R. How do I do it?

I tried it using paste0
Let us take only 5 as number of repetitions:

```
paste0("trial",1:5,"= Ozone", 1:5)
```

I get this as result.

```
"trial1= Ozone1" "trial2= Ozone2" "trial3= Ozone3" "trial4= Ozone4" "trial5= Ozone5"
```

But it is not the way I wanted it. I want the output to come out as it is like (not even in inverted commas):

```
('trial1' = Ozone1, 'trial2' = Ozone2, 'trial3' = Ozone3, 'trial4' = Ozone4, 'trial5 = Ozone5)
```

Also as you can see, it is not a string i.e. output should not come between inverted commas as "........". I want it as it is exactly.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will generate the string you want...

```
paste0('(',paste0("'trial",1:1000,"'= Ozone",1:1000,collapse=' ,'),')')
```

This will print the string without quotes...

```
print(paste0('(',paste0("'trial",1:10,"'= Ozone",1:10,collapse=' ,'),')'), quote=FALSE)
```

I hope it answered your question...

Comment: Thanks! But how do i remove the inverted commas from the output which occur at the start and at the end of the output? "..." I do not want the output to be string, i just want it to be flat out statement. In simple words without inverted commas. Just this ...... not this "......."

Comment: I need to put this whole statement in place of blank without the quotes in the following command
data <- data[, "=:" blank]
How do I do this? cat and even print wont work!

Comment: I will suggest.. Frame new question with your dataset sample... And also mention why you want to do that... It may be possible that you are doing something which can be done some other way easily and efficiently...

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the single quotes, ie `\'`, and use the `collapse` argument of `paste0`:

```
 paste0("(", paste0("\'trial",1:5,"\' = Ozone",1:5, collapse=", "), ")")
[1] "('trial1' = Ozone1, 'trial2' = Ozone2, 'trial3' = Ozone3, 'trial4' = Ozone4, 'trial5' = Ozone5)"
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do i remove the inverted commas from the output which occur at the start and at the end of the output? "..."

Comment: Wrap `cat` around it, but in what context are you wanting to use the output?

Comment: I need to put this whole statement in place of blank without the quotes in the following command
data <- data[, "=:" blank]
How do I do this? cat and even print wont work!

Comment: You could create the whole command as a string, `parse` and then `eval` it